# Moving UIButton dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ios, dynamic, uibutton, position

I have been searching the internet for answers but it seems that I can't any answers. Well, what I have been trying to do is to move a UIButton dynamically based on the what the height of a textfield is.

For example, I have this: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."

Of course the textfield will increase it's height based on this code I found.

```
CGRect frame = txtCardOffer.frame;
frame.size.height = txtCardOffer.contentSize.height;
txtCardOffer.frame = frame;
```

And to increase UiScrollView height,

```
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
container.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
container.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
for (UIView* view in container.subviews)
{
    if (!view.hidden)
    {
        CGFloat y = view.frame.origin.y;
        CGFloat h = view.frame.size.height;
        if (y + h > scrollViewHeight)
        {
            scrollViewHeight = h + y;
        }
    }
}
container.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
container.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

[container setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(container.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight))];
```

Everything's now set except for the submit button. I don't know how to make that button change it's vertical position based on the textfield's height. It's just there in the middle. As if it's using position:absolute on CSS.

Can you guys help me out? Am running out of keywords for searching on Google.

Comment: Find the x and y where you want to show your button. once you are done with x,y draw that button in that frame.

Comment: So there's no way to do this automatically? I really have to make a code for it?

Comment: only one to two lines of code to draw button at x,y.

Comment: you have to deal with the UIButton frame (y coordinate which is dynamic) according to textField height which you have to fix according to Text length and Font size!!! CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

Comment: Hi Ravi, not sure but the first three codes above managed to get the correct height for UiScrollView.

Comment: Hi Ravi, I think I got what you mean. The code you sent is for dealing with UiLabels. The code I added above is for TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting button's frame as

```
[btn setFrame : CGRectMake(x, txtCardOffer.frame.origin.y+txtCardOffer.frame.size.height, 30,60)];
```

Comment: i dont think so. you have to tell the frame where you want to place your button, and its just one line code, i dont think it will be any problem.:)

Comment: I guess you're right. It so weird that I can't find any other codes on the project I inherited just like the one you posted.